# Side-loaded apps limit on WIndows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

In Windows Phone 7 there is a limit of max 10 side-loaded apps on developer unlocked device.

Is this limit still there in Windows Phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As andrewpey wrote the limit for normal accounts is still 10 apps.

It is also worth noting that for Student accounts (via Dreamspark) the limit is 3 side-loaded apps.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it's still limited to 10 apps, [according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-RU/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769512%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).