# How many apps can I deploy to windows phone 8 device for testing?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I want to buy windows phone 8 device for testing.and I have developer account.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Side-loaded apps limit on WIndows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912471/side-loaded-apps-limit-on-windows-phone-8)

Answer (score 2):

You can deploy up to ten apps on a registered device. This limit does not apply to apps that you install from the Store. You can uninstall old apps and install the new ones, if the limit is reached.

[Deploying and Testng apps in a Windows Phone device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_device)

Note: These are basic questions, better google once before asking such questions.

Comment: Are you sure? I want to deploy many apps to device when uninstall old apps and install the new ones, if the limit is reached.

Comment: Yes. The limit is , at a time you can install 10 apps only. You can uninstall and install new ones.